# How does java recognize commented applet html tag in applets program?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, applet

I used to java programs in notepad(normal text editor),Usually `/*test/*` would be counted as comments in a program which won't be interpreted by compiler,

For e.g

```
import java.io.*;

import java.sql.*;

class products

{

public static void main(String args[])

/*test /*

Here test would be considered as comments
}
```

But in applets how does `/*` recognize it in applet viewer and generate the window based on the size and code?

```
/*<applet code="myaddapplet.java" width="300" height="300">
</applet>
*/
```

how does not java take it as programming content instead of taking it as comments ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how does not java take it as programming content instead of taking it as comments ?

The Java compiler does not read that file.

It is an HTML file ... or something that generates one (e.g. a JSP).  The HTML is read on the client side by your web browser's HTML parser, not by a Java compiler.  In fact, it is likely that the user's machine doesn't even have a Java compiler installed.

The HTML parser does not recognize the `/* ... */` as a comment.  Depending on where it is, it may treat those characters as literal characters and attempt to show them to the user.

The `<applet>...</applet>` part is valid HTML ... which the HTML parser recognizes, and treats as an instruction to launch an applet.

Answer (score 1):

Err, because it's HTML, not Java?

Comment: i edited my question kindly have a look on it

Comment: It's still HTML, not Java. No amount of editing can change that.